# Symfony: Data acquisition method for specific conditions in the form

Tags: php, symfony

I want to pull down the clerk of the same shop as the logged-in staff with the Symfony 4.4 app.
Also, I want to display the logged-in staff at the beginning of the pull-down.
I'm trying with the code below, but I get the following error.
How can I meet my demands?　Looking at the documentation, I couldn't find a method that looked very good.

Similar questions are posted on the link below.
https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/comments/mkh5xh/how_to_get_data_of_specific_conditions_by/

Error

```
The value of type "object" cannot be converted to a valid array key.
```

ArticleType

```
$staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($loginStaff->getShop());

$builder->add("author", ChoiceType::class, array(
"required" => true,
"choices" => $staffs,  
));
```

Result of dump($staffs);

```
array:18 {
0 => AppBundle\Staff,
1 => AppBundle\Staff,
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use EntityType instead of ChoiceType

```
$builder->add("author", EntityType::class, array(
    "required" => true,
    "choices"  => $staffs,
    "class"    => Staff::class,
    "constraints" => [new Assert\NotBlank()],
));
```

If the field is required, it's necessary to add `NotBlank`, because the `required` param adds validation only by html.

There is [documencation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities) that could be useful for you

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for.